# Does Matplotlib have an incomplete set of Greek characters in its LaTeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Lines such as the following will work fine with matplotlib:

```
plt.xlabel('$\gamma$')
plt.xlabel('$\Gamma$')
plt.xlabel('$\pi$')
plt.xlabel('$\Pi$')
```

And they give the nice, LaTeX font on the graph.

But if I try to run any of these:

```
plt.xlabel('$\beta$')
plt.xlabel('$\Beta$')
plt.xlabel('$\alpha$')
plt.xlabel('$\Alpha$')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 
\Beta
^
Unknown symbol: \Beta (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

This makes no sense. I need to use beta in this plot, and I do not want to have to resort to just calling it "beta." How do I get this to work?

Comment: Aren't the capital of Alpha and Beta just A and B? You should also use an r prefix, e.g. `r"\beta"` to get a raw string literal which ignores the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Smith's answer (see comment above) did it. I just had to use this line:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\beta$')
```